# how to stop EC2 instances with windows command line?

Tags: powershell, command-line, amazon-ec2

I tried to do the following:

1. Download: client EC2 in https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351. And save that in C:/AWS/CLI.
2. Create in the environment variables, a new system variable.

   - Name: `JAVA_HOME`
   - Value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`
3. Create other new system variable.

   - Name: `EC2_HOME`
   - Value: `C:\AWS\CLI`
4. Edit the value of the system variable `Path`, and add `%EC2_HOME%\bin`.
5. Create other two system variables:

   - System variable name: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, value: my access key.
   - System variable name: `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, value: my secret key.
6. Open my windows command line and execute the code:

   ```
   ec2-stop-instances <id_instancia> –region <region>
   ```

I received the error:

```
the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Those API tools look somewhat old.

These days, it is recommended to use either:

- [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (Windows, Mac, Linux)
- [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) (Windows only)

If you like PowerShell, use that one. Otherwise, go for the AWS CLI. There is good documentation for both.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extremely easy way to stop the instance from the instance's cmd, that is

```
shutdown /s
```

That will shutdown (and stop, not terminate) the EC2